# Vertical alignment in formatting plain-text proc report output

Tags: formatting, sas, proc

I'm trying to format the output from `proc report` in plain text. I have a variable by which I group observations and which spans two lines. This causes an apparent line break and separates the grouped observations. Is there any neat way to fix this?

The following minimal example illustrates the problem.

*EDIT:* The program should preferably also work for only one observation in some subjects.

**Program:**

```
* Toy data ;

data mydata;
  length subj $ 20;
  input subj $ val val2;
  datalines;
ID001|M 7.1 5.2
ID001|M 7.1 4.9
ID001|M 7.1 5.3
ID001|M 7.1 5.6
ID001|M 7.1 5.7
ID020|F 7.1 3.2
ID020|F 7.3 2.9
ID020|F 7.2 0.9
ID300|M 7.2 1.2
ID300|M 7.2 1.8
;
run;

* Create report ;

ods listing;
proc report data=mydata headline headskip split='|';
  column(subj val val2);
  define subj / order flow 'Subject ID|Sex';
  define val  / 'Value 1';
  define val2 / 'Value 2';

  break after subj / skip;
run;
ods _all_ close;
```

**Output:**

```
Subject ID                                
Sex                     Value 1    Value 2
------------------------------------------

ID001                       7.1        5.2
M                                         
                            7.1        4.9
                            7.1        5.3
                            7.1        5.6
                            7.1        5.7

ID020                       7.1        3.2
F                                         
                            7.3        2.9
                            7.2        0.9

ID300                       7.2        1.2
M                                         
                            7.2        1.8
```

**Desired output:**

```
Subject ID                                
Sex                     Value 1    Value 2
------------------------------------------

ID001                       7.1        5.2
M                           7.1        4.9
                            7.1        5.3
                            7.1        5.6
                            7.1        5.7

ID020                       7.1        3.2
F                           7.3        2.9
                            7.2        0.9

ID300                       7.2        1.2
M                           7.2        1.8
```

**Alternative desired output:**

```
Subject ID                                
Sex                     Value 1    Value 2
------------------------------------------

ID001                     
M                           7.1        5.2
                            7.1        4.9
                            7.1        5.3
                            7.1        5.6
                            7.1        5.7

ID020                                       
F                           7.1        3.2
                            7.3        2.9
                            7.2        0.9

ID300                       
M                           7.2        1.2
                            7.2        1.8
```

Or something similar to these that visually separates the groups clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I indented gender but you can remove that.  Make sure you 2 or more obs per subject.

```
data mydata;
   length subj $ 20;
   input subj $ val val2;
   length sex $3;
   sex = '  '||scan(subj,-1);
   subj = scan(subj,1);
   datalines;
ID001|M 7.1 5.2
ID001|M 7.1 4.9
ID001|M 7.1 5.3
ID001|M 7.1 5.6
ID001|M 7.1 5.7
ID020|F 7.1 3.2
ID020|F 7.3 2.9
ID020|F 7.2 0.9
ID300|M 7.2 1.2
ID300|M 7.2 1.8
;;;;
   run;

proc print;
   run;
* Create report ;

*ods listing;
proc report data=mydata headline headskip split='|' list 
/*      showall*/
      ;
   column(subj sex stub val val2);
   define subj / order noprint;
   define sex  / order noprint;
   define stub / computed width=10 'Subject' '  Gender';
   define val  / 'Value 1';
   define val2 / 'Value 2';
   break after subj / skip;
   compute before subj;
      xsubj = subj;
      endcomp;
   compute before sex;
      j = 0;
      xsex = sex;
      endcomp;
   compute stub / char length=20; 
      j + 1;
      if      j eq 1 then stub = xsubj;
      else if j eq 2 then stub = xsex;
      else                stub = ' ';
      endcomp;
   run;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, it should also work for 1 observation per subject. Do you have a suggestion for handling that?

Comment: I reckon you will also want OPTIONS MISSING=' '; if you don't already have it.  May I ask why you're using LISTING output?

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure all subjects have two or more obs by adding one if needed.

```
data addonemaybe / view=addonemaybe;
   set mydata;
   by subj;
   output;
   if first.subj and last.subj then do;
      call missing(of val:);
      output;
      end;
   run;
```

Comment: This belongs in the other answer, not as a separate answer.

Comment: I didn't want to edit my answer.  Down-vote or edit you are the moderator.

Comment: I'm not a moderator, actually (they have diamonds next to their name) ...  but you should edit it in the other answer.  This isn't a forum - answers should be self contained, not sequential.

Comment: The answer does provide an answer to the question that that I implied in my first answer and the OP confirmed and asked in a comment to that answer.